# System.Progress not firing events on main thread after WinForms dialog was shown

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, synchronizationcontext

I have a WPF dialog that shows a progress meter control, and a background task ([`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)) that provides a stream of progress updates that need to be fed into the progress meter. The mediator between the two is a [`System.Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx) object.

This all works perfectly under "normal" circumstances:

- The background task calls `System.IProgress.Report()` on some thread X that is not the main thread.
- The `System.Progress` object does its internal magic where it switches threads
- The `System.Progress` object fires the `ProgressChanged` event on the main thread.
- The progress meter control is updated on the main thread (which owns the control)

Now, if I open *any* WinForms dialog, then close it, then start my background task, the `System.Progress` suddenly fires the `ProgressChanged` event not on the main thread, but on some thread Y that is not the main thread. This of course leads to an `InvalidOperationException` because the event handler tries to update the WPF progress meter control on a different thread than the one that owns the control.

I noticed the docs for `System.Progress` saying that:

> [...] event handlers registered with the `ProgressChanged` event are invoked through a [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) instance captured when the instance is constructed. If there is no current [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) at the time of construction, the callbacks will be invoked on the [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

This seems to match what I can observe, because this is how the lower part of the call stack looks like when `System.Progress` fires its event in the bad case:

```
[...]
bei System.Progress`1.InvokeHandlers(Object state)
bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
bei System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
bei System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I checked the value of the [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) property at the time when the `System.Progress` object is created, but it is never null. The `SynchronizationContext` object returned by the property has the following types:

- Good case (i.e. before opening a WinForms dialog): The object is a `System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`
- Bad case (i.e. after opening a WinForms dialog): The object is a `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext`

Unfortunately I have not much experience with WinForms, and none at all with `SynchronizationContext`, so I am quite at a loss what is going on here.

Why does opening a WinForms dialog change the `SynchronizationContext.Current` value? Why does this have an effect on how `System.Progress` behaves? Is there a way how to "fix" the problem, short of writing my own replacement of `System.Progress`?

**EDIT:** I might add that the executable is an MFC application at the core, the .exe project is compiled with /CLR, and the C# code that I am looking at is invoked via C++/CLI. The C# code is compiled for (and running under) .NET framework 4.5.1. The complicated setup is due to the application being a legacy beast with modern attitudes :-), but so far this has worked out very well for us.

Comment: Are you showing dialog form on non main UI thread?

Comment: @IvanStoev No, I'm showing the WinForms dialog on the main UI thread. I'm also showing the WPF progress dialog on the main UI thread.

Comment: Looks like you are right. `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` is automatically uninstalled when the internal message loop count becomes 0. This normally does not happen in WF application because there is always 1 main loop running (`Application.Run`), but with your app architecture... I have no idea, even if you trick it somehow, it really requires message loop support in order to work correctly.

Comment: So would it be out of the question to instantiate a new instance of `System.Progress` any time you start your background work?  Are you using the same instance of `System.Progress` for the life of the application?

Comment: @FelixCastor No, I'm not using the same `System.Progress` instance over and over, a new `System.Progress` instance gets created every time just before the background task is created. The new instance then picks up whatever `SynchronizationContext` is current.

Comment: Why not try it the other way around then?  Keep the same instance.

Comment: @FelixCastor I might have been tempted to do so, but in the meantime I have another occasion unrelated to `System.Progress` where code that should be running on the main thread is running in some other thread. I now believe that the reset to the `SynchronizationContext` is the root cause that I must address, or more evil things will pop up in unexpected corners.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have experimented with saving the current `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext `, then restoring it after it gets uninstalled (with `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext()`). That _seems_ to work fine, but as I said in my question I have no experience with synchronization contexts. Would you say that restoring the previous context is something that can be done without getting into further "trouble"?

Comment: I don't know. There must be reason for MS putting that code. From the other side, if it works for you... :)

Comment: There is more to it, crystal ball says that the ShowDialog() call is made on a worker thread.  Don't do that.  Assigning WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false; would be another way.

Comment: @HansPassant Your crystal ball is cloudy today - the ShowDialog() call is made on the main UI thread. For instance, I see `WinMainCRTStartup()` and also `AfxWinMain()` towards the bottom of the call stack.

Comment: Hmya, it could not possibly have guessed that it is actually MFC that runs the dispatcher loop.  Having no less than 3 gui class libraries that critically depend on having the correct dispatcher doing the work, what could possibly go wrong?  Yeah, that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting finding. By default the `WindowsFormSynhronizationContext` is automatically installed inside any `Control` class (including `Form`) constructor, as well as on first message loop, and is uninstalled after the last message loop. Normally this uninstall behavior is not observed because WinForms applications usually live inside the `Application.Run` call.

But not in your case. The issue can easily be reproduced by the following simple WF application:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var form = new Form();
            Trace.WriteLine(SynchronizationContext.Current?.GetType().ToString() ?? "null");
            form.ShowDialog();
            Trace.WriteLine(SynchronizationContext.Current?.GetType().ToString() ?? "null");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
```

As a workaround, I would suggest you setting the main UI thread `SynchronizationContext` manually at the beginning of your application and then turn [`AutoInstall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) off, which will prevent that uninstall behavior (but could cause issues if some other part of the application replaces the main thread `SynchronizationContext`):

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false;
```